# Subsituting larger image when mouse over

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement something like this

but want it only want the enlarged substitution to take effect when the mouse over is on a certain portion of the original photo. Anyone know how I can go about that?

```css
.effectback {
  display: block;
  background: url('https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7042/6873010155_d4160a32a2_s.jpg') no-repeat;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.effectfront {
  opacity: 0;
  border: none;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.effectfront:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s;
}
```

```html
<div class="effectback">
<img class="effectfront" src="https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7042/6873010155_d4160a32a2.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: Read about sprites my friend: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Comment: http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/

Answer (score 1):

Use background images, then you can create an invisible element that when the mouse hovers over, you switch the background image of the other element.

```
.social > .hidden > .fb {
    background: url(//cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-ra1ho85/templates/__custom/images/fb1.png?t=1460125436);
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 35px 35px;
}

.social > .hidden:hover > .fb {
    background: url(//cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-ra1ho85/templates/__custom/images/fb2.png?t=1460125436);
    display: inline-block;
    background-size: 35px 35px;
}
.social{
  position:relative;
}
.hidden{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  height:10px;
  width:10px;
  background:transparent;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="social">
    <div class="hidden">
        <div class="fb"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, when you hover over the top left of the social div, there is a 10px by 10px where the .hidden element will be trigged to :hover, and change the .fb element's background image.

Hope this helps.

Comment: But what mark up would I need. <div class="social">
<img class="social" src="images/PO7296325-front-cu.png" />
</div> Does not work.

Comment: You need to add the hidden element. See my edit with HTML.

Comment: Not sure what I might be missing. Have tried it and nothing appears. Here's my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gatorreina/fasm5ua5/